# ExceptionHandler: 404 вместо ожидаемой возвращаемой сущности

Tags: java, spring, исключения, exception-handler

У меня есть Exception, который я и написал:

```
public class UserIdentificationException extends RuntimeException {

    private MobileApiResponseCode code;

    public UserIdentificationException(MobileApiResponseCode code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public MobileApiResponseCode getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Есть обработчик исключений, тоже написанный мной:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MobileApiExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = UserIdentificationException.class)
    public ApiResponse<MobileMessageResponse> handleUserIdentificationException(UserIdentificationException e) {
        return new ApiResponse<>(ApiBaseResponseCode.OK, e.getCode().getDescription());
    }
}
```

Есть тестовый контроллер:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ApiResponse<MobileMessageResponse> test() {
    throw new UserIdentificationException(MobileApiResponseCode.INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN);
}
```

Ожидается, что при запросе я получу заявленное в обработчике содержимое ApiResponse, но вместо этого приходит пустота и статус 404.

Подскажите, что не так?

UPD: ответ, конвертированный в JSON, выглядит так:

```
{"code":15,"errorMsg":"invalid auth token"}
```

А уже при попытке его вернуть происходит 404.

Comment: Не туда делаете запрос

Comment: В каком смысле? Если можно, дайте более развёрнутый ответ, с примером и описанием.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, оказалось, что не хватает аннотации `@ResponseBody` над методом обработчика.